# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType' when building pyomo model

Tags: python, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I have a problem with a pyomo model, which has been partly answered here already: [TypeError PYOMO: Defining constraints based on pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903101/typeerror-pyomo-defining-constraints-based-on-pandas-dataframe)

However, first of all I don't really understand the problem and if I apply the proposed fix I get another error.

So here I will provide you with some of my code. I have a photovoltaic model with some constraints and a solar thermal model with some constraints that theoretically could fight for the same available area:

```
#total PV power generation from ground/tilt roof/wall at teach timestep
m.pv_groundGen = Var(year_i, ts_i, within = NonNegativeReals, initialize = 0)
m.pv_roofGen = Var(year_i, ts_i, within = NonNegativeReals, initialize = 0)

#PV covered roof area at different angles
m.pv_roofPanelArea = Var(r_az, r_tilt, within = NonNegativeReals, initialize = 0)
m.pv_groundPanelArea = Var(within = NonNegativeReals, initialize = 0)
if "pv_ground" in ders_df.index.values:
    
    # Relation between installed capacity and panel area        
    def pv_groundPanelAreaRule(m):
        return m.c_c["pv_ground"] == m.pv_groundPanelArea * pv_eff
    m.const_pvGroundArea = Constraint(rule = pv_groundPanelAreaRule) 

    #Some constraints describing pv generation cut for visibility

    #Limits the area available for ground and flat roof pv
    
    if "solar_thermal_ground" not in ders_df.index.values: 
        def panel_groundAreaLimit(m):
            return m.pv_groundPanelArea <= pv_groundareaAvail * pv_gcr_ground
        m.const_panelGroundAreaLimit = Constraint(rule = panel_groundAreaLimit)
    
if "pv_roof" in ders_df.index.values:
    
    # Relation between installed capacity and panel area
    def pv_roofPanelAreaRule(m):
        return m.c_c["pv_roof"] == sum(m.pv_roofPanelArea[az, tilt] for az in r_az \
            for tilt in r_tilt) * pv_eff
    m.const_pvRoofArea = Constraint(rule = pv_roofPanelAreaRule)
    
    #Some constraints describing pv generation cut for visibility
    
    #Limits the area available for ground and flat roof pv
    if "solar_thermal_roof" not in ders_df.index.values:
        def panel_roofAreaLimit(m, az, tilt):
            return m.pv_roofPanelArea[az, tilt] <= pv_roofwallareaAvail.at[az, tilt] * pv_gcr_roof
        m.const_panelRoofAreaLimit = Constraint(r_az, r_tilt, rule = panel_roofAreaLimit)

m.st_groundPanelArea = Var(within = NonNegativeReals, initialize = 0)
m.st_roofPanelArea = Var(r_az, r_tilt, within = NonNegativeReals, initialize = 0)

if "solar_thermal_ground" in ders_df.index.values:
    
    def stUsefulHeatG_rule(m,y,ts):          
        return sum(m.heat["solar_thermal_ground", hCons, y, ts] for hCons in hIn) == \
            (st_eff_0*irrad_tilt_flat[ts] *1000 - st_a1*(st_Tf-temp[ts]) - \
            st_a2*((st_Tf-temp[ts])**2)) * m.st_groundPanelArea
    m.const_stUsefulHeatG = Constraint(year_i,ts_i,rule = stUsefulHeatG_rule)
        
    def stpanelAreaG_rule(m):
        return m.c_c["solar_thermal_ground"] == m.st_groundPanelArea * 0.717 # official conversion factor 
    m.const_stpanelAreaG = Constraint(rule = stpanelAreaG_rule)
    
    if "pv_ground" in ders_df.index.values:
        def panel_groundAreaLimit(m):
            return m.pv_groundPanelArea/pv_gcr_ground + m.st_groundPanelArea*1.7 <= pv_groundareaAvail
        m.const_panelGroundAreaLimit = Constraint(rule = panel_groundAreaLimit)
    else:
        def panel_groundAreaLimit(m):
            return m.st_groundPanelArea*1.7 <= pv_groundareaAvail
        m.const_panelGroundAreaLimit = Constraint(rule = panel_groundAreaLimit)
    
if "solar_thermal_roof" in ders_df.index.values:
    
    def stUsefulHeatR_rule(m,y,ts):          
        return sum(m.heat["solar_thermal_roof", hCons, y, ts] for hCons in hIn) == \
            sum((st_eff_0*irrad_tilt_tilt_df.at[az,tilt][ts] *1000-st_a1*(st_Tf-temp[ts]) - \
            st_a2*((st_Tf-temp[ts])**2)) * m.st_roofPanelArea[az, tilt] for az in r_az for tilt in r_tilt)
    m.const_stUsefulHeatR = Constraint(year_i,ts_i,rule = stUsefulHeatR_rule)
        
    def stpanelAreaR_rule(m):
        return m.c_c["solar_thermal_roof"] == sum(m.st_roofPanelArea[az, tilt] \
                for az in r_az for tilt in r_tilt) * 0.717 # official conversion factor 
    m.const_stpanelAreaR = Constraint(rule = stpanelAreaR_rule)
    
    if "pv_roof" in ders_df.index.values:
        def panel_roofAreaLimit(m, az, tilt):
            return m.pv_roofPanelArea[az, tilt]/pv_gcr_roof + m.st_roofPanelArea[az, tilt] * \
                1.7 <= pv_roofwallareaAvail.at[az, tilt]
        m.const_panelRoofAreaLimit = Constraint(r_az, r_tilt, rule = panel_roofAreaLimit)
    else:
        def panel_roofAreaLimit(m, az, tilt):
            return m.st_roofPanelArea[az, tilt] * 1.7 <= pv_roofwallareaAvail.at[az, tilt]
        m.const_panelRoofAreaLimit = Constraint(r_az, r_tilt, rule = panel_roofAreaLimit)
```

Now the problem is, if I build the model, which includes the part I posted here, I get this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType' (showing me this `line st_a2*((st_Tf-temp[ts])**2)) * m.st_groundPanelArea`
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError: stUsefulHeatG_rule() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'ts'

Now, if I take the advice from the link above and create the variable m.st_groundPanelArea which seems to be the trouble maker with a Set [1,] I get a new error:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'

Reading the other thread and the error codes I reckon this all has something to do with an interaction problem of numpy and pyomo but I really do not understand why I do not have the same issue with m.pv_groundGen for example

Thanks a lot and all the best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post does not have all of the variables defined in order to really troubleshoot this well.  If the below doesn't answer your question, you should edit your post by removing unnecessary parts of the model and include variable definitions and a snippet of sample data to **reproduce the error.**

That said, I think you are getting bit by another manifestation of the same issue regarding the interaction of non-indexed `pyomo` variables with `numpy` data types.  I think that both `pyomo` and `numpy` are trying to override some of the basic algebraic functions to produce consistent data types.  `pyomo` is trying to create `pyomo.expressions`, while `numpy` is trying to maintain `ndarray`s.  (There's probably a fuller description of this issue in the `pyomo` bug report on this issue, but that, I think, is biting you.)

My suggestion, *especially* when you have a singleton `pyomo` variable, is just to *not* use numpy arrays or variables in your model.  Just force convert them to basic python types and you'll be fine.  (As shown in linked post.)

If you want to persist with the way it is now, you should pull the equation out of your constraint and tinker with it after defining all the variables and **ensure** that it evaluates to a `pyomo` expression.  When the variable is a singleton, order matters when interfacing with `numpy` arrays.  Yes, this is ugly.  So strongly recommend either indexing **all** variables or converting everything to basic types, which is easy.

```
In [57]: import numpy as np                                                                                            

In [58]: from pyomo.environ import *                                                                                   

In [59]: m = ConcreteModel()                                                                                           

In [60]: s = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])                                                                                   

In [61]: m.x = Var(s)                                                                                                  

In [62]: m.y = Var()   # a non-indexed variable!                                                                       

In [63]: temp = np.array([1.5, 2.5])                                                                                   

In [64]: type(m.x[1] * temp[1])                                                                                        
Out[64]: pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr.MonomialTermExpression

In [65]: type(temp[1] * m.x[1])                                                                                        
Out[65]: pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr.MonomialTermExpression

In [66]: #  All is good.... these above evaluated to pyomo expressions                                                 

In [67]: type(m.y * temp[1])                                                                                           
Out[67]: pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr.MonomialTermExpression

In [68]: type(temp[1] * m.y)                                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-e1ff132af45b> in <module>
----> 1 type(temp[1] * m.y)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'

In [69]: type(temp[1] * Var())                                                                                         
Out[69]: numpy.ndarray

In [70]: # noted that when the variable is not constructed in a model, the behavior evaluates to an ndarray
```

Comment: Hi @AirSquid Thanks for you answer! I connet uprate it yet unfortunately :(
I just turned around the order (before np * pyomo --> now pyomo *np) and now it works :D
I guess whatever is used first overwrites the other...

Comment: Also when you right forceconvert to a python type, I guess you mean `float(irrad_tilt_flat[ts])`  if irrad_tilt_flat[ts] is the array? 
In the beginning I had everything in pyomo sets and parameters. But it is sooooo much slower to build the model (quite a big model) so I returned to numpy, which seems to bite me now haha...

Comment: @Aggotrom even if you can't upvote the answer, if it answers the question, you can "accept" it by hitting the checkmark...  It isn't clear from what you have posted why the construction would be slower with pyomo sets & parameters.  Were you doing "math" on them as that would be the only thing I could think of?  If the pyomo sets/params are burdensome, I would fall back to basic lists and dictionaries *not* numpy, unless you are doing vectorized calculations somewhere *outside* the model.  And yes, for conversions, I would just use a list comprehension...  `temp = [float(t) for t in temp]`

Comment: Perfect thanks, I accepted it! Yes I guess I perform some maths on them but nothing crazy.  It is not the solving time that goes up drastically but the building time.
Yeah in many cases I already have dictionaries. Thanks for the advice!